# strange behavior from normal.log_prob when calculating gradients in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I have the following model:

```
from torch.distributions import Normal

class Policy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_inp, num_out, hidden_dim):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(num_inp, hidden_dim)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        
        self.mean_linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_out)
        self.log_std_linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_out)

    def forward(self, obs):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(obs))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        mean = self.mean_linear(x)
        log_std = torch.clamp(self.log_std_linear(x), min=-2, max=20)
        std = log_std.exp()
        normal = Normal(mean, std)
        x_t = normal.rsample()
        log_prob = normal.log_prob(x_t)
        log_prob = log_prob.sum()
        return x_t, log_prob
```

Then I run a simple test as follows:

```
import torch.autograd as autograd

model = Policy(17, 6, 50)
inp = torch.rand(1, 17)
x_t, log_prob = model(inp)

grads = autograd.grad(log_prob, model.parameters())
```

`grads` is what I expected to be it, except that for the layer `self.mean_linear` the gradient is always `0` (for the weights and the bias). It shouldn't be. I don't understand what's wrong with this as it is very simple. How to get the correct gradient?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question in the [pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/), were get I got an answer. Find it [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/strange-behavior-of-log-prob-when-calculating-gradient/156270/2). The reason why the gradient with respect to the mean is 0 is when computing the log probability, the means get canceled since the reparameterization trick was used. I won't go into much detail as that was clearly explained in the answer attached.